How do virtue ethics and utilitarianism compare on the issue of disconnecting life-support?
While reading this interesting Question about approaches to the issue of abortion, I thought it would be illuminating to consider the situation of disconnecting life-support.
For utilitarianism, it would be unclear how the happiness of the person to be allowed to die is involved, if they are not conscious and not expected to recover. The others involved will see them die after a longer or shorter time regardless, so their happiness is not much of an issue either. You could say that we shouldn't waste resources on a hopeless case. (Please, please refrain from bringing in the faint hope that they might recover, just to narrow and simplify this question and answers.)
For virtue, it is known that everyone will die sooner or later, and wishing for oneself to be prolonged to no purpose would likely not be the wish of the person who will die. Hopefully others agree.
So, without risking answering the question myself, I would like to know more from you about what utilitarianism and virtue ethics have to say and if they largely agree or not?

This is a long article describing the evolution of technology, medical practice, law, and ongoing philosophical challenges in the United States: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6913806/. Virtue ethics in medicine is to value life and life-pleasure for self and others. I think this value is driven by the biological appetite and conscious desire for vitality - the ability to live. Paradoxically one can use vitality to devalue or discount either the vitality of self, or the vitality of others, or the vitality of plants or animals, and we do so when we kill to eat or feed our ego, etc

@SystemTheory this is a good article! Thanks, very helpful to this question.

The devil is always in the details. With moral questions this means: the devil is in the exact circumstances.
For instance, what evidence is there that the patient is not conscious (we better be totally sure about that)? Did the patient themselves express earlier in life what they would like to have done in a situtation like this, for instance in the form of a "Living Will" (if so, surely that should play a role in the decision process)? If so, do we have documentary evidence, or do we just need to trust someone's word (we better have some document)? Is there actually no hope for recovery? Who decided to put the patient on life support? What kind of life support - heart-lung machine, or something less severe? Why was this done? Apparently, at that point, there must have been some hope of recovery? If so, when and how did this change? By which authority could someone or a group of people decide to disconnect the life support -- who are the "we" here that could make the decision? What consequences could this further have for us? Are we liable for criminal prosecution? Is the life support an expensive, scarce resource? Are there others who do have hope of recovery and who would be better served? -- There may also be other motives in play. Does the patient leave a large estate? Do the people who advocate for disconnecting life support have ulterior motives to  propose this? Does hospital staff have ulterior motives?
In the general, hypothetical case, I would argue that it is justified to disconnect life support in the case that at least the following four conditions all apply

there is no reasonable hope of recovery
the subject is unconscious, unresponsive to outside stimuli and there is no hope of regaining consciousness; we may reasonably assume the subject is not sentient and we may assume we do not deprive the subject of possible future happiness or freedom
the life support system is a scarce resource and will or may be needed for others (the costs of the system need to be offset to other costs of care)
the situation is a drain on the happiness and freedom of friends and family; prolonging the situation increases the unhappiness and decreases the freedom of those people (including hospital staff)

This justification is based simply on the general principle of preventing unnecessary harm and unnecessary restrictions of freedom. In this situation it is not only justified to disconnect life support, the people who have to make the decision are, in principle, morally obliged to do so. (Again, exactly when very much depends on the situation, and of course on to what extent the above criteria are all met.) -- So, I don't think "virtue ethics" has much to say about this.
But this is not the whole story. These kind of situtations don't exist in some philosophical vacuum. There is a social-political context; there are consequences to any action. If you accept this, you also have to accept that we (as law makers) are obliged to make general rules and practices - we have to institute laws and protocols - concerning this kind of situation. Protecting the patient against possible forms of abuse, neglect, carelessness; protecting against possible ulterior motives of others. Protecting doctors and hospitals, and anyone involved, against incrimination if they take part in this decision or in its realization. There should be agreed-upon protocols in place to regulate as good as possible when and how this decision may be made, how it is to be performed, and who is to be involved. Part of establishing these kind of regulations would also need to be informing the public about them, and asking for regular feedback.
At this point the utilitarian argument could be made. The general justification for establishing those laws is that this would indeed benefit everyone, at least everyone involved in these kind of cases -- others might remain indifferent. Not setting up laws implies that some very difficult situations are left to the discretion (or despair) of individuals - which doesn't seem to be in anyone's benefit (except those who might want to abuse these kind of situations).

The historical overview that @SystemTheory linked to Looking Back at Withdrawal of Life-Support Law and Policy to See What Lies Ahead for Medical Aid-in-Dying, by Alexander Morgan Capron (Dec. 2019) gives a very good, concise overview of how the ethical problem came to be, how attitudes changed from the early '60s to now, and how practices, new institutions (e.g. ethical committees in hospitals), legal rulings and laws came to be. We basically justify withdrawal of life support, if we accept that a person on life support has a right to (be left to) die - especially when the person has made a living will, appointing someone else to be their agent when they themselves are incapacitated. The article contrasts the way in which this right was established with developments around the question of whether medical active euthanasia should be allowed (and if so, in which form). In both cases court rulings  led the way (or are leading the way), and legislation followed...

... but the judicial task was a very different one: not to resolve a dispute between private parties [which was the setting for the court cases about withdrawal of life support] but to define the proper scope of state power to control (through the criminal law) the actions of private parties [which is the setting for medical-aided euthanasia].

The article ends a little ominously with

[T]he development of law on medical aid-in-dying is now proceeding along a different path than the one that ran from the first to the second stage of law on forgoing life-support, separated by the stark differences described above. (...) As they proceed—either along their two paths or on some combined path—the physicians, nurses, hospital administrators, legislators, judges, and lawyers on both paths may wonder whether they are muddling through or are merely in a muddle.

In my opinion, it's also ominous that the right to withdraw life-support is argued constitutionally, in the US, as being based on the right to privacy -- similar to Roe vs Wade. Legal rights can never be taken for granted.

"In the general, hypothetical case, I would argue that it is justified to disconnect life support in the case that..." Are you saying all 4 of the items that follow must apply, only one of them, or what?

Ok, so barring abuse and motivated reasoning we pass a few laws and leave it to the people directly involved, extend protection to medical practitioners acting in good faith... Seems similar to the abortion case, but I'll leave that aside. What if there is no documentation of prior wishes, our hands are tied then?

"... in the case that ...." all 4, at the very least

Why would the ready availability of the apparatus affect the moral reasoning?

ulterior motive in the dictionary sense of "An alternative or extrinsic reason for doing something, especially when concealed or when differing from the stated or apparent reason."

@D.Halsey - The apparatus creates the whole problem and dilemma in the first place and I'm assuming it's a costly resource - there will at least be a cost to the hospital - in terms of personel and money. Someone will have to pay. There is also then an opportunity cost - since there are/may be always more patients, and people on wait lists, etc etc. Only in the (I think) hypothethical situation that there is no cost, or that the family/friends can easily bear this cost, the apparatus would be irrelevant for the moral considerations.

Yes, there seems to be a gap in morality between what it prescribes and the possible circumstances. That's where people want answers, so we need a list of accepted responses from: all powers can brought to the situation, down to: I'm in a life-raft in the ocean with only a cup of water available.

"Rule a big country/the way you cook small fish" (Laozi, 60) - not stirring too much.

Based on the article linked in the comments at the top, the rules have slowly encompassed more situations with fewer hurdles, while still preventing abuse or manipulation. These rules, plus the people directly involved (like, able to touch the person) make the decision, and it appears to be working well. I'm not aware of any unintended consequences.

Reading it now - The first sentence seems very apt: "Sixty years ago, Yale professor Ed Lindblom famously described the process by which public policies are created as “the science of ‘muddling through’”. (This by itself also seems a criticism of much of academic ethical philosophy - especially of the belief in an ill-defined 'rationality' and of interminable, but irrelevant debates. Philosophy seems to be in a perpetual muddle - and often making actual muddles more muddled rather than helping to resolve them.)

The article actually makes a very interesting link (implicitly) to virtue ethics - e.g. in pointing out that the reluctance of doctors to "pull the plug" is/was partially also due to their pride in their (medical science's) miraculous powers to keep people alive...

Medical miracles are always possible.  We know this because they happen.  Excluding them, is a flawed assumption, and makes the thinking here invalid if applies to our world.  I will not accept your first two assumed bullets.
It is also important to realize there are multiple variants of moral theories.  Rule utilitarianism, for instance, tries to address some of the known failings of standard utilitarianism, including the impossibility of actually performing the utilitarian calculus in -- basically any actual case. But rules -- always lead to some flawed outcomes, and the original idea of utilitarianism was to account for the uniqueness of situations...  I think the better approach is to assume summing is valid, and kind of guesstimate it.  Additionally, the extension of utilitarianism to all adult mammals, to all animals, or to all life, produce very different outcomes than a human focused utilitarianism.
Virtue ethics is even more diverse, as there are multiple different virtues assumed in particular ethical thinking.  Examples are stoicism, Confucianism, Samurai code, and Love/Truth higher values virtue ethics.
Also, one's metaphysics, and in particular, what one thinks a self is, matters significantly. I will answer with the plurality view in philosophy, that people (and animals/plants for that thinking) are selves that are emergent from matter.
So, I will try with these examples to answer the question.

Utilitarianism for humans: The equipment to maintain anyone on life support is very expensive, compared to the basic health care that people in for example Bangladesh receive.  It should be reserved for extremely rare cases of a high payoff, such as young people likely to recover from their situation. In the example you cited, there is sunk investment in a wealthy nation that chooses to not share medical resources to those who would far better benefit, so is already far from a utilitarian ideal.  But even in that case, there is no gain from maintaining a non-agent's life, while there is cost and suffering within that particular society.  Pull the plug.

Utilitarianism for adult animals, animals and/or all life:  There is so much very simply alleviated suffering for adult animals, there is never any opportunity cost justification to maintain any human on life support.  Pull the plug, shut down the power, close the hospital, and devote all those resources to improving the welfare of moral patients!  Pull the plug and throw it away!

Stoicism -- Humans die.  We must reconcile ourselves to this, and just try to achieve what we can in life, without futilely attempting to fight the inevitable.    Only in rare circumstances, particularly among the young or parents with dependents, is life support appropriate.  Pull the plug.

Confucism: The welfare of society matters, and this includes respect for one's elders.  The effort to save the ill senior is admirable.  But also, respect for the way things are, the inevitability of death, and the cycle of birth, maturation, aging and death, are also valuable.  The appropriate care has been provided, the extreme measures of life support are not.  Pull the plug.

Samurai: Honor the life, and honor the memory of a life boldly lived.  Life support at the end of that life, is not honoring the memory of a true warrior. Pull the plug.

Love and Truth: Truth is not particularly useful here, except for the family to accept the unlikelihood of recovery.  Love -- applies to the family as well as the patient. Except the patient is -- likely gone forever already. The welfare of the family and care for them usually calls for doing all one can, then accepting the inevitable when it is -- reasonably understood as inevitable.  Pull the plug.


The major ethical view that would give different answers is Rights based ethics. If the patient has arranged the insurance and resources for care, and set up the care, then pulling the plug while they have any hope of recovery (and they always will) is a violation of their rights.

Hm, not accepting that there would in certain concrete cases no reasonable, science-based hope of recovery -- seems to me a religious belief in miracles.  It's fine for anyone to believe in miracles, but I don't see how this can be a basis for policy making (given that "we" are not living in a theocracy (yet), at least not in Western Europe or the US, and need to come to agreement). And policy making is definitely a requirement, admitted by anyone involved -- as evidenced by history.

So, the overall answer seems to be against life-support beyond some reasonable boundary. I wonder what light this would shed on the abortion argument, considering that there are people outside the womb already with needs, problems and other situations?

@mudskipper -- There are, for multiple cases where medical staff have given up hope, surprise recoveries among patients.  That this has long been true is well documented:  https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/just-dying-to-get-out/  Living systems are immensely complex, and have always occasionally done things our regularity-based predictions do not account for.
